# Not one, not unanimous, but exactly two unique approvers to dictate a successfully approved step

Tags: trigger, workflow, approval-process

This is quite a brief question, and I believe the concept is also small and easily handled  so I'll make this short and snappy.

Situation:

- 6 Approvers.
- Only two are required to confirm their approval for the step to be declared as approved.

So it's obvious already we can't use `Unanimous` or the `First-Response` functionality of approvals.

Remember this can be ANY of the 6 approvers so attempting to delegate it to just two of the six won't work either.

One more thing to note is that we are aware you can create two separate steps where you can basically resubmit the same step twice however we can't (using declarative techniques) omit the user who has already submitted the first approval confirmation so he'd in effect be able to submit it twice, which is not acceptable.

Does anyone have any ideas at all for me? All thoughts much appreciated.

P.S. Potentially open to triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea (that has some practical limitations). I'll be curious to see if there is a better approach. We'll assume the target object is `Foo__c`

1. On `Foo__c` create five lookups to User: `Step2ApproverPoolMember1__c`,`Step2ApproverPoolMember3__c`,`Step2ApproverPoolMember3__c`,`Step2ApproverPoolMember4__c`, and `Step2ApproverPoolMember5__c`
2. For Step2 of the Approval Process, use the `Automatically assign to approver(s)` radio button and the `add row` command and make each row equal to one of the five related user look fields defined in #1
3. In Step 1 of the Approval process, use a field update as an approval action that updates `Foo_c.approvalStatus__c` to 'step1Approved`.
4. Use a before update `Foo__c` trigger to (if `approvalStatus__c` is `step1Approved` and the relatedUser fields are all null to examine the user that approved in step1 and then set the values of the five related user fields to everyone but the step1 approved-by user.

The hypothesis here (and unproven by me) is that the approval step1 approval action field update will update the database before the approval process engine decides which users will see the approval request in the second step of the process.

Assuming the hypothesis is correct, the obvious practical limitation is the fixed number of related User fields defined in `Foo__c`. If you suddenly had a pool of seven approvers, you'd need to add metadata and change the trigger.

Comment: Yeah, this is a great theory and a solid explanation to follow. However this is correct there is a large chance that the user base could change, changing metadata is not a solid solution for me. I would have to keep it as dynamic as possible. I'm wondering if the second approval step could pull through the associated users with step 1 at run time and then assess from there.

Comment: The technique doesn't care if the actual users change, only if the number of approvers in the pool changes. You could define 10 related user fields.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, "base" wasn't the correct word to use what-so-ever, instead "user scale" is more fitting. Again, the scale could change sporadically depending on changes.